# Learning MVVM. Calling Methods

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm currently learning how `MVVM` works and gettings a bit confused.

**What I Have Now:** I've got a `MainWindow.xaml` and have made a button that adds in `UserControl1.xaml` adding it to a ContentControl, which all works great. I've got a folder named ViewModels with a class named `SettingsViewModel.cs` and another folder named Views with a UserControl named `SettingsView.xaml`

**What I'm trying to figure out:** In the User Control I'll have things like buttons, checkboxes, and some other stuff, I want to be able to have a button press in the MainWindow to call a method where I can do stuff like changing the visibility of items among other things. How I go about calling this method from the MainWindow and where to put the method [`SettingsViewModels.cs` or `SettingsView.xaml`].

I'm still very new to programming so I'm probability leaving out a bunch of info, so ask me any question.

I have accually got this to work the other way around; calling a method in MainWindow from a UserControl like this...

```
//this is in the UserControl
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow callMethod = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
    callMethod.MyMethod1();
}

//this is in the MainWindow
pubic void MyMethod1()
{
    //whatevery i want here
}
```

Comment: Bind the `Command` property of the `Button` in the `UserControl` to an `ICommand` property of the view model of the window?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to consider. In MVVM, View communicate to ViewModel through bindings and ViewModel communicate to the View through events typical from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ICollectionChanged`. Buttons should be binded to a property of type `ICommand`. The ViewModel should not know about WPF control stuff like `Visibility` etc.
To change visibility you use an `IValueConverter` called [BooleanToVisiblityConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?view=netframework-4.8).

Without quite understanding what you are asking, here is some pseudo code of how I would do it.
The structure of your files doesn't matter, but dividing them into Views and ViewModels is a good idea.

> Disclaimer: This code will not run, shows only the concept. I left Visual Studio on my other computer.

**ViewModel**:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ICommand OpenCommand { get; }
    public object Child { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        OpenCommand = new RelayCommand(Open);
    }
    
    private void DoOpen()
    {
        Child = new ChildViewModel();
    }
}

public class ChildViewModel
{
    public bool ShowSomething { get; }
}

public class Program
{
    private void SomeStartupLogic()
    {
        var window = new MainWindow();
        windows.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(); // or use an IoC container
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<Window class="MainWindow">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ChildViewModel}">
        <ChildView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Child}"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding OpenCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>



<UserControl class="ChildView">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConvert"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Something" Visibility="{Binding ShowSomething, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConvert}/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Links**

[MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern)

[Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/may/mvvm-commands-relaycommands-and-eventtocommand)

[PropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification)